# preg_replace for replacing comment text in a file

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, replace

In a file, I want to replace

```
COMMENT AS `<some_comment>`
```

with

```
COMMENT '<some_comment>'
```

That is, replace `COMMENT AS` with just `COMMENT`, and replace the backticks around the following comment - but without replacing backticks anywhere else.  How would I do this, from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sed, with careful quoting:

```
sed "s/^COMMENT AS \`\(.*\)\`$/COMMENT '\1'/"
```

Here I used double-quotes to surround the statement because of the internal single-quotes.

The back-ticks have to be escaped from the shell.

The parenthesis are escaped to make sed capture them (for later re-insertion with the `\1` token).

I've also anchored the text to the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of line.